# how to fill empty dictionary in a while loop with time stamp as key and a value

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary

I have a while loop and i am getting a value from a website every second.
I would like to have a dictionary with a date/timestamp as key and the value from website as value. As it is a loop, each key/value pair will need to be appended to dictionary.
Thank you in advance.

```
d = {}
x=1
while x < 9:
time.sleep(1)
d.append(dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) #this is key
d.append(website_var) #this is value
x = x+1
print(d)
```

{1/1/18 10:20:25 : 77.60, 1/1/18 10:20:26 : 77.65, etc:etc}

Comment: `d[key] = value` is the syntax for assigning a new key with the given value or for updating a key's value.

Comment: So your statement would just be `d[dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")] = website_var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
import datetime
import time

d = {}
x=1
website_var = 'Some Value'
while x < 9:
    time.sleep(1)
    d[datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")] = website_var
    x = x+1
print(d)
```